# Get 2 x getElementById elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to amend the below code to include the value for persDonateAllocat:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAddPersonalDonation(personaldonation, id){
            if(isNaN(personaldonation)){
                alert("Please enter only round numbers and no cents."); 
            }else{
                window.location = "adopt.php?action=add&personaldonation=" + personaldonation + "&id=" + id + "&all=" + persDonateAllocat;
            }
        }
    </script>

<a href=\"javascript:doAddPersonalDonation(
            document.getElementById('personaldonation').value,$id
            )\">Add To Cart</a>
```

I have tried the below code but clicking on the link now does nothing:

```
<a href=\"javascript:doAddPersonalDonation(personaldonation, persDonateAllocat){
            document.getElementById('personaldonation').value,$id;
            document.getElementById('persDonateAllocat').value;
            } \">Add To Cart</a>
```

I have added this and it now works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAddPersonalDonation(personaldonation, id){
        var persDonateAllocat= document.getElementById('persDonateAllocat').value;
            if(isNaN(personaldonation)){
                alert("Please enter only round numbers and no cents."); 
            }else{
                window.location = "adoptions_2.php?action=add&personaldonation=" + personaldonation + "&id=" + id + "&all=" + persDonateAllocat;
            }
        }
    </script>

<a href=\"javascript:doAddPersonalDonation(
                document.getElementById('personaldonation').value,$id
                )
                \">Add To Cart</a>
```

Comment: Do this inside the method

Comment: Can you elaborate please, I am no Javascript fundi?

Comment: I added an example answer

Answer (score 1):

How about this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FK95r/).**

**HTML:**

```
<a id="myLink">Some link</a>
<input id="personaldonation" />
<input id="persDonateAllocat" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    var id = 123;
    var personaldonation = $("#personaldonation").val();
    var persDonateAllocat = $("#persDonateAllocat").val();
    window.location = "adopt.php?action=add&personaldonation=" + personaldonation + "&id=" + id + "&all=" + persDonateAllocat;
});
```

Comment: I have resolved this now and edited my question to reflect the solution I used. Someone posted the answer but removed it even though it was the correct solution. Thanks for your help.